# Sending Date in Json String Vb Script

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to include a date in Json string in Vbscript

```
d=FormatDateTime(Now)
PaymentDate =(FormatDateTime(d,2))



Set objXmlHttpMain = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
    strJSONToSend = "{""PaymentDate"": " & PaymentDate & " ,""Months_Paid"": "& MONTHS_PAID &"}"
    objXmlHttpMain.open "POST",URL, False 
    objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    objXmlHttpMain.send strJSONToSend
    Logger.Info PaymentDate
```

My output returns [image]

If I enter the date in my string like so ""06/21/2017"" the post goes through no problem. When i try to use the variable i get no errors but the post does not get sent through. How do i send todays date in my json string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to put the variable between double quotes as you do manually.

```
strJSONToSend = "{""PaymentDate"": """ & PaymentDate & """ ,""Months_Paid"": "& MONTHS_PAID &"}"
```